# How to write more than one value per key into an XML file?

Tags: xml, dictionary, key

I have a simple XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<dictionary>
  <Item>
    <Key>
      <string>Stations</string>
    </Key>
    <Value>
      <string>Station 1</string>
    </Value>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Key>
      <string>Vendors</string>
    </Key>
    <Value>
      <string>Vendor 1</string>
    </Value>
  </Item>
</dictionary>
```

So I want to save more than one value per key. In this example I'd add a vendor 2 or something like that. I need to be able to store more than one station, more than one vendor, but I have no idea how to do this in XML. I'm using it in my C# application to read data that changes from time to time so I can't hard code it. I just want to be able to have like a "list" per key. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have an XML like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<dictionary>
  <Item>
    <Key>
      <string>Stations</string>
    </Key>
    <Value>
      <string>Station 1</string>
      <string>Station 2</string>
    </Value>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Key>
      <string>Vendors</string>
    </Key>
    <Value>
      <string>Vendor 1</string>
      <string>Vendor 2</string>
      <string>Vendor 3</string>
    </Value>
  </Item>
</dictionary>
```

You can access the list in value by using [XMLNode.ChildNodes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.childnodes(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: How do I read the child nodes using a simple LINQ query? The existing code converts the XML document into a dictionary before I use it. So I have the query the Dictionary. How do I do that? Do you have an idea? Sorry, I haven't worked with XML previously. The followed query is how I view the single station I have in the document at the moment.

Comment: `var query = from t in test
                        where t.Key == "Stations"
                        select t.Value;`

Comment: The test is basically just the XML file being written into a Dictionary